# Mock util function Angular 6

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a `route guard` that uses a util function.

This looks like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateChild, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../../services';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import objectFromHash from '../../utils/object-from-hash/object-from-hash.util';

@Injectable()
export default class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    let hasValidSession: Observable<boolean>;

    const { id_token, access_token } = objectFromHash(route.fragment);

    hasValidSession = this.authService.isSessionValid(id_token, access_token);

    return hasValidSession;
  }
}
```

I am currently trying to test this using `Jasmine` - however I am unsure how I can mock out the `objectFromHash` util function.

I would like to test that this function is called during the execution of my route guard.

My spec file looks like this

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import AuthGuard from './auth.guard';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services';

describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  it('should pass the route hash to a util method', () => {
    const { authGuard } = setup();

      // I AM UNSURE WHAT TO DO HERE?
  });

  const setup = () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useClass: MockAuthService,
        },
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    const authGuard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);
    const authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    const objectFromHash = TestBed.get(objectFromHash);

    return { authGuard, authService };
  };
});

const MOCK_TOKEN = '';

export class MockAuthService {
  isSessionValid(id_token?: string, access_token?: string) {}
}
```

Attempting to access `objectFromHash` returns an error reading

```
​​TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngInjectableDef' of undefined​​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by importing the util and spying on it.

As the util is a default export I did have to do this `spyOn(helper, 'default')`

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'; 
import AuthGuard from './auth.guard';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services';

import * as helper from '../../utils/object-from-hash/object-from-hash.util';

describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  it('should pass the route hash to a util method', () => {
    const { authGuard, props } = setup({});
    const objectFromHashSpy = spyOn(helper, 'default').and.returnValue({
      id_token: 'foo',
      access_token: 'bar',
    });

    authGuard.canActivateChild(props);

    expect(objectFromHashSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  const setup = propOverrides => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useClass: MockAuthService,
        },
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    const props = Object.assign({ fragment: null }, { ...propOverrides });

    const authGuard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);
    const authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);

    return { authGuard, props, authService };
  };
});

const MOCK_ROUTE_FRAGMENT = '';

export class MockAuthService {
  isSessionValid(id_token?: string, access_token?: string) {}
}
```